# Definition of formal adjoint of covariant derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-operators, connections

I read in *Einstein Manifolds, L. Besse* that the covariant derivative $D: \mathcal{J}^{(r,s)}(M)\to \Omega^1(M)\otimes\mathcal{J}^{(r,s)}(M)$ admit an formal adjoint $D^*:\Omega^1(M)\otimes\mathcal{J}^{(r,s)}(M) \to \mathcal{J}^{(r,s)}(M)$ as follows:
$$D^*T(X_1,\cdots,X_r)=-tr \{(X,Y)\to D_XT(Y,X_1,\cdots,X_r)\}$$
where $X_i$s are vector field and $T\in \Omega^1(M)\otimes\mathcal{J}^{(r,s)}(M)$.

> In general, for every linear differential operator(LDO) $D:\Gamma(E)\to\Gamma(F)$ where $E$ and $F$ are vector bundle over $M$, admit a formal adjoint operator $D^*:\Gamma(F)\to\Gamma(E)$ defined by:
> $$\int_M\left<D\xi,\eta\right>dvol_g=\int_M\left<\xi,D^*\eta\right>dvol_g$$
> where $\xi\in\Gamma(F), \eta\in\Gamma(E) $ with compact support. [(Difinition 2.2)](http://users.math.msu.edu/users/parker/ga/geometryprimer.pdf)

**Question**: Which of the above difinition is related to the following equation:
$$\nabla^*\circ \nabla=-tr\nabla^2$$
and how can I prove this equation?

Related: [Formal adjoint of the covariant derivative](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/142913/formal-adjoint-of-the-covariant-derivative)

Comment: Do you mean $\nabla^* \circ \nabla$ in the final equation? For example, acting on one forms, the "equation" that you wrote is not true (you can check it on $\mathbb{R}^n$ to see there it is only true on closed one-forms, a fact which also uses that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is Ricci-flat).

Comment: @Willie. Thanks for your point. I edited it.

Comment: What happens if you then just plug and chug? (Using, say, the top definition, which is a special case of the second one.)

Comment: But How i prove it?

Comment: Can you prove it for scalar functions? On $\mathbb{R}^n$? Show your work and say where you are stuck. If you want help, you need to tell us what you need help with.

Comment: Excuse me. Can you explain how can obtain first definition from the second?

Comment: I'm voting to move this question to Math.SE where it is more appropriate. In the mean time, since I may forget later, I'll write up an answer which would be suitable for Math.SE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### How to obtain the first definition from the second

Let $E$ be the bundle $\mathcal{J}^{r,s}$ and $F$ be the bundle $\Omega^1 \times \mathcal{J}^{r,s}$. The precise definition of $\mathcal{J}^{r,s}$ doesn't matter that much here, but for concreteness let's say it is the set of rank $(r,s)$ tensor fields over $M$ on which the metric inner product extends as $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$. More precisely, if $\{e_i\}$ is a frame of orthonormal vectors and $\{f_i\}$ a frame of orthonormal covectors, we have, for $W,Z\in \Gamma(\mathcal{J}^{r,s})$
$$ \langle W, Z\rangle = \sum_{i_1, \ldots, i_r, j_1, \ldots, j_s = 1}^{\dim M}  W(e_{i_1}, \ldots, e_{i_r}, f_{j_1} , \ldots, f_{j_s}) Z(e_{i_1}, \ldots, e_{i_r}, f_{j_1} , \ldots, f_{j_s}) $$

The inner product can be defined on $F$ (aka $\Omega^1 \times \mathcal{J}^{r,s}$) analogously.

Now, let $W \in \Gamma(\mathcal{J}^{r,s})$ and $Z\in \Gamma(\Omega^1 \times\mathcal{J}^{r,s})$, the definition requires $\nabla^*$ satisfies

$$ \int \langle \nabla W, Z \rangle ~\mathrm{dvol}_g = \int\langle W, \nabla^* Z\rangle ~\mathrm{dvol}_g \tag{1}$$

for any choice of $W$ and $Z$. Now, a direct computation using the metric compatibility of the inner product shows you that, if we write $P\in \Gamma(\Omega^1)$ as

$$ P(X) = \sum_{i_1, \ldots, i_r, j_1, \ldots, j_s = 1}^{\dim M}  W(e_{i_1}, \ldots, e_{i_r}, f_{j_1} , \ldots, f_{j_s}) Z(X, e_{i_1}, \ldots, e_{i_r}, f_{j_1} , \ldots, f_{j_s}) $$

we have, by Leibniz rule,

$$ \sum_{e_i} (\nabla_{e_i} P)(e_i) = \langle \nabla W, Z\rangle - \langle W, \nabla^* Z \rangle \tag{2}\label{lb}$$

where $\nabla^*$ is defined as in your first definition. To conclude if suffices to observe that if $W, Z$ have compact support, the left hand side of \eqref{lb} integrates to 0 by the divergence theorem.

### How to obtain the formula for the Laplacian

Directly compute using the first definition you have

$$ \nabla^* \circ \nabla W (\cdots)= - \mathrm{tr} \{ ((X,Y) \mapsto \nabla_X (\nabla W)(Y, \cdots)  = \nabla^2_{X,Y} W(\cdots)\} $$

Comment: I do not understand your question. Can you be more precise?

Comment: Ok. What is the role of vector fields $X_1,\cdots, X_n$ used in the first definition . can you re define $D^*T(X_1,\cdots,X_r)=-tr \{(X,Y)\to D_XT(Y,X_1,\cdots,X_r)\}$ without using $X_i$'s?

Comment: The $X_1, \ldots, X_r$ are just arbitrary place holders; they are included to make the "trace" operation concrete (so you know which two slots to trace). If you use the index notation the definition is $$(D^*T)_{i_1, \ldots, i_r}^{j_1, \ldots, j_s} = g^{kl} D_k T_{l, i_1, \ldots, i_r}^{j_1, \ldots, j_s} $$ without resorting in explicitly specifying the place holder vector fields. Alternatively you can also use Penrose's diagrammatic notation and it will also not require the place holders. // The role of $X_1,\ldots$ is no different from the role of $x$ in the function definition $f(x) = x^2$.

Comment: Thanks. Can you answer my another question? Is $\nabla\circ\nabla _{X,Y}T=\nabla_{\nabla_XY}T-\nabla_X\nabla_Y T$?

Comment: (1) That's a matter of notation and should be introduced by whatever thing you are reading. (2) But almost certainly not, the right hand side has the wrong sign. It is more likely $\nabla_X\nabla_Y - \nabla_{\nabla_X Y}$.

Comment: Is this your mean $\nabla\circ\nabla _{X,Y}=\nabla_X\nabla_Y - \nabla_{\nabla_X Y}$? Can you give some hints to prove it?

Comment: Why would you even consider "proving" a notational definition?

Comment: This is not a notation. I found its proof in [here](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~jeffv/courses/865_Fall_2007.pdf). Thanks.

Comment: @WillieWong: could you elaborate on how you get $(2)$? I have tried multiple times but I get a bunch of extra terms I can't show are zero, unless I also make the assumption that $\nabla_{e_i}e_j=0$ and $\nabla_{e_i}f_j=0$ at $p\in M$ and use tensoriality. I know I can always make such an assumption, but I was wondering if I could get the calculation to work out in a general orthonormal frame. Thanks.

Comment: @AdrianoMeis: you should certainly adapt your frame locally. If not, you will have to deal with a bunch of Ricci rotation coefficients, and then you have to carefully cancel stuff using antisymmetry (that $\langle \nabla_{X} e_i, e_j\rangle = - \langle e_i, \nabla_X e_j\rangle$).

Comment: I also be stuck by (2).  What I try :
$$
\sum_i(\nabla_{e_i}P)(e_i) = \sum_i[e_i(P(e_i))-P(\nabla_{e_i}e_i)]
=
e_i[W(...)Z(e_i,...)] 
-
W(...)Z(\nabla _{e_i}e_i,...)    \\
=
e_i(W(...))Z(e_i,...) +W(...) e_i(Z(e_i,...))
-
W(...)Z(\nabla _{e_i}e_i,...)
$$
Then, I don't know how to calculate it.