# Formal adjoint of divergence operator

Tags: riemannian-geometry, tensors, ricci-flow

Picture bottom is from Topping's Lectures on the Ricci flow ([author website](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/%7Emaseq/RFnotes.html), [zbMath link](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1105.58013)).

I wanto to show  the formal adjoint of $\delta$ is covariant derivative. The definition of formal adjoint is in picture below (in fact, I am not sure which definition is suitable).

> **Definition 2.2** The (formal) adjoint of a linear operator $D: \Gamma(E) \rightarrow \Gamma(F)$ is the operator $D: \Gamma(F) \rightarrow \Gamma(E)$ defined by
> $$
> \int_{M}\langle D \xi, \eta\rangle d v_{g}=\int_{M}\left\langle\xi, D^{*} \eta\right\rangle d v_{g} \tag{2.14}
> $$
> for all $\xi \in \Gamma(E), \eta \in \Gamma(F)$ with compact support.
> [(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwHIL.jpg)

I want to prove the formal adjoint of $\delta$ is covariant derivative. For simple, I choice $T= T_{ij} dx^i\otimes dx^j$ and $G= dx^b$.  What I calculate:
$$
\delta (T)(\partial_k) 
= 
-g^{ij} (\nabla T)(\partial_i, \partial_j, \partial_k ) 
=
-g^{ij} (\nabla_{\partial_i} T)(\partial_j, \partial_k ) 
\\
=-g^{ij}[\partial_i(T(\partial_j, \partial _k))- T(\nabla _{\partial_i}\partial_j, \partial_k)
- T(\partial_j, \nabla _{\partial_i}\partial_k)
]
\\
=
-g^{ij}\frac{\partial T_{jk}}{\partial x_i} +g^{ij}\Gamma_{ij}^aT_{ak} +
g^{ij}\Gamma_{ik}^aT_{ja}
$$
where $\partial_i$ is the basis vector.  Therefore, I have
$$
\delta (T) = [-g^{ij}\frac{\partial T_{jk}}{\partial x_i} +g^{ij}\Gamma_{ij}^aT_{ak} +
g^{ij}\Gamma_{ik}^aT_{ja}] dx^k
$$
so
$$
\langle \delta (T), G\rangle _g =
-g^{ij}g^{kb}\frac{\partial T_{jk}}{\partial x_i} 
+
g^{ij}g^{kb}\Gamma_{ij}^aT_{ak} 
+
g^{ij}g^{kb}\Gamma_{ik}^aT_{ja}  
\tag{2}
$$
On the other hand,  there is $\nabla dx^b = -\Gamma_{ij}^b dx^i \otimes dx^j$. So, I have
$$
\langle T, \nabla G \rangle_g = T_{ij}\Gamma_{kl}^b g^{ik} g^{jl} \tag{3}
$$
Next, I want to show
$$
\int_M \langle \delta(T), G\rangle dV_g = \int_M\langle T, \nabla G \rangle dV_g  
\tag{4}
$$
About (4), I have
$$
\text{LHS} = \int_M (-g^{ij}g^{kb}\frac{\partial T_{jk}}{\partial x_i} 
+
g^{ij}g^{kb}\Gamma_{ij}^aT_{ak} 
+
g^{ij}g^{kb}\Gamma_{ik}^aT_{ja}  ) 
dV_g
\\
\text{RHS}
=
\int_M  (T_{ij}\Gamma_{kl}^b g^{ik} g^{jl})  dV_g
$$
According to Deane's hint, I guess I should integral by parts to get
$$
\int_M (-g^{ij}g^{kb}\frac{\partial T_{jk}}{\partial x_i})  dV_g
=
\int_M (\frac{\partial g^{ij}}{\partial x_i}g^{kb}  T_{jk} )  dV_g
+\int_M ( g^{ij}\frac{\partial g^{kb}}{\partial x_i}  T_{jk} )  dV_g
$$
since $\partial M = \varnothing$.  Next, I think I should use the
$$
\Gamma_{ij}^k = \frac{1}{2}g^{kl}(
\frac{\partial g_{jl}}{\partial x_i}
+
\frac{\partial g_{li}}{\partial x_j}
-
\frac{\partial g_{ij}}{\partial x_l}
)
$$
and integral by parts. But its really complex. So before do it, I want to know whether the way is right ?

Besides, I am not familiar with the integral by parts on manifold.

> We will be regularly using the divergence operator $\delta: \Gamma\left(\otimes^{k} T^{*} \mathcal{M}\right) \rightarrow$ $\Gamma\left(\otimes^{k-1} T^{*} \mathcal{M}\right)$ defined by $\delta(T)=-\operatorname{tr}_{12} \nabla T$. Again, $\operatorname{tr}_{12}$ means to trace over the first and second entries (here of $\nabla T$ ).
>
> **Remark 2.1.1.** $\color{red}{\textbf(}$ The formal adjoint of $\delta$ acting on this space of sections is the covariant derivative $\nabla: \Gamma\left(\otimes^{k-1} T^{*} \mathcal{M}\right) \rightarrow \Gamma\left(\otimes^{k} T^{*} \mathcal{M}\right) .$$\color{red}{\textbf)}$ However, if one restricts $\delta$ to a map from $\Gamma\left(\wedge^{k} T^{*} \mathcal{M}\right)$ to $\Gamma\left(\wedge^{k-1} T^{*} \mathcal{M}\right)$ then its formal adjoint is the exterior derivative (up to a constant depending on one's choice of inner product). Moreover, we shall see later that if $k=2$ and one restricts $\delta$ to a map from $\Gamma\left(\operatorname{Sym}^{2} T^{*} \mathcal{M}\right)$ to $\Gamma\left(T^{*} \mathcal{M}\right)$, then its formal adjoint is $\omega \mapsto \frac{1}{2} \mathcal{L}_{\omega^{\#}} g$ where $\#$ represents the musical isomorphism $\Gamma\left(T^{*} \mathcal{M}\right) \mapsto \Gamma(T \mathcal{M})$ (see $[14$, $(2.66)]$, for example).
> [(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnXoC.jpg)

Comment: The eq. (1) is the definition of formal adjoint and why you want to prove a definition? What you suppose for def of formal adjoint?

Comment: @C.F.G I want to prove the $\delta $ and $\nabla$ satisfy the (1). Since the $delta$ or $\nabla$ is not defined using (1), I want to check it.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1842938/definition-of-formal-adjoint-of-covariant-derivative). Basically you misunderstood (1).

Comment: @ArcticChar  I get stuck in (2) of  [Willie Wong's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1842938/definition-of-formal-adjoint-of-covariant-derivative).

Comment: Are you sure that the formal adjoint of $\delta$ is covariant derivative $\nabla$? I think the formal adjoint of $\delta$ is exterior derivative $d$.

Comment: @C.F.G I am sure, I get it from the Topping's book.  In fact, for some cases, the formal adjoint of $\delta$ is exterior derivative, which is stated in Remark 2.1.1, and I have alter the last picture which contain all  cases.

Comment: The computation of the formal adjoint has to be done using the integral in Definition 2.2 and integration by parts. (2) is indeed not equal to (3).

Comment: @Deane  With your hint, I find a way (I have added it in question) to calculate (4) for special $T$ and $G$. But it is complex, and I am not sure whether it is right.  Whether there is an easy way ?

Comment: The more useful formula for Christoffel symbols is $$\partial_kg_{ij} = g_{ip}\Gamma^p_{kj} + g_{jp}\Gamma^p_{ik}$$

Comment: And if you are not already familiar with integration by parts on a Riemannian manifold, I suggest that you learn or review that carefully before doing this exercise.

Comment: When you integrate by parts, do it in local coordinates. The $dV_g$ factor has to be differentiated as well.

Comment: @Deane  You are really a good teacher.  You suggest me to review the integration by parts on a Riemannian manifold, in fact, you hint me that I should to calculate $\frac{\partial \sqrt{\det(g)}}{\partial x_i}$.  Up to a minus, I get (2.1.4). Thanks again. 谢谢。

Comment: @Deane  Besides, the formula for Christoffel  is useful, and  $\partial_k g^{ij}$ also be.  ;-)  haha.