# Formal adjoint of divergence which is restricted on $\Gamma(\wedge^k T^*M)$

Tags: riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

I want to show the red line. In fact, in [another problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4259902/formal-adjoint-of-divergence-operator) ,
with many help, I get the formal adjoint of divergence without restrict. Beforehand, I think I can deal the red line if I know how to get the formal adjoint of divergence. But turns out I was way too simple. I have no idea of proving red line.

What I try:

Assume
$$
T=T_{ij} dx^i \wedge dx^j \in \Gamma(\wedge^2 T^* M),~~~G=dx^b
$$
I try to show
$$
\int_ M \langle \delta(T), G\rangle dV_g = \int_M \langle T, d(G) \rangle dV_g
\tag{1}
$$
First, I have  $T_{ij}=-T_{ji}$ and
$$
\delta(T)(\partial_k) = -g^{ij}(\nabla T)(\partial_i, \partial_j, \partial_k)
\\
=(-g^{ij}\partial_i T_{jk} + g^{ij}\Gamma_{ij}^a T_{ak} + g^{ij}\Gamma_{ik}^a T_{ja}) dx^k
$$
Therefore, there is
$$
\langle \delta(T), G\rangle = 
-g^{ij}g^{kb}\partial_i T_{jk} 
+ 
g^{ij}g^{kb}\Gamma_{ij}^a T_{ak} 
+ 
g^{ij}g^{kb}\Gamma_{ik}^a T_{ja}
$$
Besides, since $d(G)=d(dx^b)=0$, I have
$$
\langle T, d(G)\rangle =0
$$
So, Proving (1) is equal to prove
$$
\int_ M \langle \delta(T), G\rangle dV_g = 0
$$
In fact, there are  (in fact, there's a lot of calculation left out, they are really fussy)
$$
\int_ M \langle \delta(T), G\rangle dV_g 
=
\int_M(-g^{ij}g^{kb}\partial_i T_{jk} 
+ 
g^{ij}g^{kb}\Gamma_{ij}^a T_{ak} 
+ 
g^{ij}g^{kb}\Gamma_{ik}^a T_{ja}) dV_g
\tag{2}
$$
and
$$
\int_M (-g^{ij}g^{kb}\partial_i T_{jk} ) dV_g
=
\int_M 
(\partial_i g^{ij}   g^{kb} T_{jk} 
+
 g^{ij}  \partial_i g^{kb} T_{jk} )dV_g
+
g^{ij}   g^{kb} T_{jk} \partial_{x_i}(dV_g)
\\
=
\int_M  
(
-g^{ak}   g^{ij}\Gamma_{ia}^b T_{jk}
-g^{ab}   g^{ij}\Gamma_{ia}^k T_{jk}
-g^{ai}   g^{kb}\Gamma_{ia}^i T_{jk}  
)
dV_g
\tag{3}
$$
Combining (2) and (3), I have
$$
\int_M\langle \delta(T), G\rangle  
= 
\int_M (-g^{ak}g^{ij}\Gamma_{ia}^b T_{jk}) dV_g
=0
\tag{4}
$$
the last equlity of (4) is because $T_{ij}=-T_{ji}$.

> [image]

Comment: The process is exactly the same as the previous question, you just have to show that for $\alpha\in\Omega^{k+1}M$, $\beta\in\Omega^kM$, the following holds:$$\int_M\langle\delta\alpha,\beta\rangle dV=\int_M\langle\alpha,d\beta\rangle dV$$

Comment: @Kajelad  I add what I try in my question, I feel it is right. Could you check it for me? Thanks.

Comment: You seem to only be addressing the $k=2$ case. Also, there's no need to introduce so many Christoffel symbols; just leave the covariant derivative as $\nabla_i$. The basic argument is to show that $\langle\delta T,G\rangle=\operatorname{div}(V)-\langle T,\nabla G\rangle$ for some vector field $V$, and that $\langle T,\nabla G\rangle=\langle T,dG\rangle$ for differential forms $T,G$.